# How to add Y-Axis label in Chart.js with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I want to add string '$' the scale of my y axis values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtBd4.png)

my Code:

```
 fillData() {
  this.datacollection = {
    labels: this.time,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'PNL ($)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,80,0,0.2)',
        borderColor: 'lightgreen',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'green',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBorderColor: 'green',
        data: this.PNL,
        steppedLine: true,
        // fill: false,
      },
    ],
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          ticks: {
            // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
            callback: (value) => value + '$',
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

it should be like this 10$ in Y axis

Comment: so i figure out for now my solution is create my prop to return the value in computed and return the value :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/apertureless/pen/BZKBdX?editors=1010 for other people who stuck like me thx me later